Is every normalization a blowup?
Is the normalization of a variety always a blowup along some coherent ideal sheaf? If not, I would like to see a concrete counter-example.
Let $Y \to X$ be the normalization. The answer is positive in the following situations:

$X$ is quasi-projective. This follows since normalization is a projective birational morphism.
The singularities are mild, namely $X$ is Gorenstein and $Y$ is both Gorenstein and Cohen–Macaulay. In this case, by arXiv:1608.04525, normalization is the blowup along the conductor ideal.

By variety, I mean an integral separated scheme of finite type over the complex numbers.

Did you find an answer for this?
